# Q# Quantum.MachineLearning namespace doesn't exist error

Tags: programming, q#

I am trying to use the HalfMoon Classifier in Quantum Machine Learning Sample Examples. I am trying to run it locally. However I keep getting this error.

```
No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" exists.
```

This error is then followed by multiple errors of the identifiers under this namespace not existing. 
In my python Host.py file

I have the following Import Lines

```
import qsharp
qsharp.packages.add("Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2006.403")
qsharp.reload()
```

Edit:

Replacing Package Version and Making it same as dotnet iqsharp --version did work. However I still seem to getting fail: warnings saying identifiers don't exist and

```
No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" exists.
```

The program runs correctly but the warnings don't go away. 
Hence I ask is there anyway to fix these warnings?

Comment: What version of the IQ# kernel do you have installed? (Run `dotnet iqsharp --version` to see.) Make sure the version of the package you specify in your code matches this.

Comment: @RyanShaffer I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: Are you running the sample as is, without any modifications? Does it build and run if you run it from command line using "dotnet run"?

Comment: Thanks for your question! If I could get some additional diagnostic info, that would really help figure out what went wrong. When you ran `qsharp.reload()`, did that print any error messages to the console? What's the output of `qsharp.component_versions()`? If you could also try running the same snippet, but with the `IQSHARP_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable set to `Debug`, that would really help as well. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize to @RyanShaffer. His fix actually did work. However apparently, q# first goes into a preparing q# environment. Resulting in repeated errors about lack of identifiers from the Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning Namespace. However later when I simulate the model training and validation. They run correctly. I will edit the question to ask how to get rid of the fail: statement.